# ELF loader location on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

This may seem likea trivial question but where is the ELF loader located on Ubuntu 14.04? as well as the repository containing its source?

```
man elf
```

gives the structure of the ELF format but nothing more.

Comment: You mean the kernel? Or elf utilities?

Comment: The whole elf loader, not only the utilities.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single "elf loader." The kernel itself has an implementation for loading and executing binaries. Then there are additional libraries and utilities for working with elf files in userspace.

The following packages can be used in userspace to examine ELF files:

```
libdw1 - library that provides access to the DWARF debug information
libelf1 - library to read and write ELF files
elfutils - collection of utilities to handle ELF objects
```

Source packages are available in the Ubuntu archive. Repositories with the source are generally available at https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/$sourcpackage in bzr format. Upstream source repositories may be in many different locations. Upstream kernel source is at http://kernel.org/ of course.

Comment: +1 I was referring to the default ELF loader used to launch user space applications. The libraries offer a set of functions that allow for ELF file inspection, but where is the actual user space ELF loader that makes use of them?

Comment: You mean the kernel?

Comment: Yes, I am working on a project that implies altering the ELF loader. However, this turns out to be a finding the needle in a haystack type of problem since the kernel code base is enormous. May you please offer some hints as to where one can find the loader related modules within the kernel?

Comment: `find . -name "*elf"*` would probably be a good start in the kernel tree. Or read the docs. I'm pretty sure the docs have a list of what types of things go in what places.

Comment: I've found it; it is located in src_root/fs/binfmt_elf.c.